# Bug ou Erro de implementação com ng-if em Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, ionic

Criei uma lista onde preciso mostrar se um item já foi lido ou não, então verifico uma variável com a diretiva ng-if. Porém quando o item é aberto, e depois retorna/navega de volta a lista, não ocorre alteração na lista. Notei que  a variável que está sendo verificada com ng-if está tendo seu valor alterado, porém ng-if não reavalia quando a view é mostrada novamente. ng-if somente funciona quando a tela é carregada/recarregada, ou seja, quando fecho e abro o app novamente.

Como poderia contorna esse problema?

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in items" 
             ng-click="ctrl.marcaLida(item.id)"                                    
             ui-sref="menu.telaLeitura({idItem:item.id})">

                        <p ng-if="!item.lido_em">o</p>
                        {{item.nome}}

                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
```

Estou usando router para a navegação.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica se `ng-click="ctrl.marcaLida(item.id)"` está alterando o estado do item da opnde eles vem, banco, localstorage, etc. Por que quando vc sai da tela e volta ele esta executando o repeat dos itens e ele não está marcado como lido

Comment: O valor está sendo alterado, pois é possível imprimimos na lista. Foi a primeira verificação que fiz. Eles por padrão vem `null` e depois que um item é aberto, ele vem com o valor `2015-08-19 15:33:20` que é a data e a hora que o item foi aberto.

Comment: Manda o codigo do controller no jsfiddle antes do p coloca {{item.lido_em}} e verifica o que ta voltando quando vc muda de view e quando recarrega a pagina